# When should static methods be declared in the base class?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, class-design, static-methods

When should you use static methods in base class and protected methods? (which can be called from the derived class using base.MethodName)

Comment: Do you mean " **declare** static methods" (as in your question's title) or " **use** static methods" (as in the body of your question)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statics should only be used when your method doesn't depends on the state of the object
Protected when you want only the descendants to call methods from base.

Base.Method in general is used when overriding methods

Comment: State of the object -> the values of private and public fields / properties at a certain moment.

Comment: What is `Base.Method`? What does that last sentence mean?

Comment: @Code Gray: base.Method means, that you _always_ can call the 'adults' method in the inherited class by using the `base`-keyword

Comment: @chiffre: Oh, that's what it means? Okay, so how is that relevant? What does it have to do with the question?

Comment: I think, because Nimesh mentioned this method-call in the question - the sentence in brackets?

Comment: @chiffre: Thanks for the clarifications! What you said was exactly I intended! ;-)  @Cody Gray:My remark about base.Method is just to respond to the concern Nimesh had in his question. I don't think it is strongly connected to the actual question or at least what the title of this question says.

Answer (score 1):

Protected and static are not exclusive.

protected means you allow derived classes to access the base method.

static means the methods does not need to access the state of the instances. The are often called class methods as opposed to instance methods.

The base keyword is only useful when overriding a member from the base class (the base member is often marked as virtual then). This allows you to reference the base member in case you have overloaded it in the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

One benefit of a static method is that only one copy of the code remains in memory. This can be particularly useful if you have large collections of objects with many methods. in other words, It can reduce your memory footprint. You might also find it easier or more intuitive to control protected blocks of code when acting upon shared data in a multithreaded architecture. However, you may find it syntactically unpleasant to pass a casted (base class) instance of the object into one of it's base class static methods, and some developers may be confused by this coding style, so commenting such code is always a good idea.